# Why Flutter Container does not respects its width and height constraints when it is inside other Container

Tags: dart, flutter

```
Container(
  width: 200.0,
  height: 200.0,
  child: Container(
    width: 50.0,
    height: 50.0,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      color: Colors.red
    ),
  ),
)
```

I've been trying to find the answer in the Container class docs but I did not find it.

**Update:**

After a long time, I understood the problem.

All views inside a layout must have width, height, x position, and y position. (This applies to Android, IOS, Flutter, etc)

In my code, the inner container just has a width and height for that reason it doesn't know where to start painting.

For that reason, if the container is placed inside an Alignment widget the container gets the x position and y position and it works.

Comment: Please make the "Update" section as an answer. Its a valuable information and I can interpret all the layout complexities using it. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the update! Very useful question and answers

Answer (score 26, accepted):

All views inside a layout must have four constraints:

1. Width
2. Height
3. X position
4. Y position

This applies to Android, IOS, Flutter, etc.

In the code, the inner container just has a width and height for that reason it doesn't know where to start painting and it gets all the available space.

But, if the inner container is placed inside another layout widget that aligns its child, for example, `Center`. It will get its x and y positions.

```
Container(
   decoration : BoxDecoration(color : Colors.green),
   width: 200.0,
   height: 200.0,
   child: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 50.0,
          height: 50.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                       color: Colors.red
                    ),
            ),
        )
)
```

[image]

The inner container in red, the outer container in green.

Answer (score 89):

Constraints in Flutter works a bit different than usual.
Widgets themselves do not have constraints.

When you specify a `width`/`height` on a `Container`, you're not constraining `Container`. You're constraining the **child** of `Container`.

`Container` will then size itself based on the size of its child.

As such, parent widgets always have the last word on how their descendants should be sized.

If you want to go around this, you have to use `Align` widget:

```
Container(
  width: 200.0,
  height: 200.0,
  child: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
    child: Container(
      width: 50.0,
      height: 50.0,
      decoration:
          BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.red),
    ),
  ),
);
```

---

This may seem weird and limiting. But this single weirdness is the reason why Flutter's layout is so powerful and composable.

Comment: From where did you get that knowledge? I have been looking at docs but I have not found anything like that. Especially this: "When you specify a width/height on a Container, you're not constraining Container. You're constraining the child of Container"

Comment: You can find it right [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Container/constraints.html). Container combines its width/height properties with its constraints (if set) to constrain its child.

Comment: This is not Container specific. It apply to all Flutter widgets. I don't think there 's any documentation about this, I saw it by experience and looking at the source code

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind, setting width or height of a container, it's same as setting min-width and max-width or min-height and max-height at the same time.

Your case for the inner [Container](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) according to the documentation will be:

> If the widget has no child and no alignment, but a height, width, or constraints are provided, then the Container tries to be as small as possible given the combination of those constraints and the parent's constraints.

Since your outer container gives minWidth=minHeight=200 constraints to the inner container, thus the size of your inner container cannot be less than Size(200, 200).

---

In support of Rémi Rousselet's answer, the Align widget, same as `Center` widget, will expand to fit its parent's constraints, if its parent has constraints, and position its child in the specified alignment.

> If the widget has an  [alignment](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container/alignment.html), **constraints**, and the parent provides bounded constraints, then the  [Container](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html)  tries to be as small as possible given the combination of those constraints and the parent’s constraints, and then positions the child within itself as per the  [alignment](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container/alignment.html).

In this case, the outer Container has an Align widget as child (an alignment), constraints, and the parent provides bounded constraints, thus it tries to be as small as possible given the combination of its constraints and the parent’s constraints, which is `Size(200, 200)`.

You might be wondering why does the inner Container has the size of `50*50`, instead of `200*200`, since its parent (outer Container) has specify the `minWidth=minHeight = 200`. The reason is that as mentioned before the Align widget will expand to fit its parent constraints, so in this case the Align widget will expand to fit the outer `Container`'s constraints, i.e. it will have the size of `Size(200, 200)`, and tell its child (the inner Container), that it can be any size it wants, but not bigger than my size, `200*200`. Therefore, the information of minWidth and minHeight of the outer Container that is supposed to be pass to the inner Container is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Some additonal information for the "Update" section of the question:

As metioned above,

> All views inside a layout must have width, height, x position, and y position. (This applies to Android, IOS, Flutter, etc)

> In my code, the inner container just has a width and height for that reason it doesn't know where to start painting.

The reason why the inner container doesn't know where to start painting is that its parent, which is the outer **Container** Widget, does not have a corresponding **RenderObject**(it doesn't implement a `createRenderObject` method), hence which can't `performLayout` alone, and here comes the big deal:

Most widgets set the offset of their children(the x, and the y position of the children) by putting the **Offset** data in the `parentData` attributes in them, and such process is done in the `performLayout` method, so in the nested **Container** usage scanarios, the inner container can't get a reasonable offset from the outer widget, and therefore setting the width and height fails working in the inner container.

Furthermore, why `Align` Widget can help solving this problem?
Take a glimpse of the `Align` source code and everything becomes clear and plain

```dart
// Align -> createRenderObject -> RenderPositionedBox -> alignChild
  @protected
  void alignChild() {
    // ....irrelevant code
    final BoxParentData childParentData = child!.parentData! as BoxParentData;
    childParentData.offset = _resolvedAlignment!.alongOffset(size - child!.size as Offset);
  }
```

And I sure believe any other Widgets similar to `Align` Widget that set the offset of their children can solve this problem as well