# How to change height of a card in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, height, flutter-card

```
Card(
  semanticContainer: true,
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
  child: Image.network( 'https://placeimg.com/640/480/any',fit: BoxFit.fill),
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
  ),
  elevation: 5,
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
)
```

Comment: You can wrap it with a Container: Container(height: 100, child: Card(
              semanticContainer: true,
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
              child: Image.network( 'https://placeimg.com/640/480/any',fit: BoxFit.fill,),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              ),
              elevation: 5,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
             ))

Answer (score 83, accepted):

To modify the width or height of a card you can wrap it in a Container Widget and provide height and/or width properties to it.

Please see below your code wrapped with a container set with height  at 500:

```
Container(
  height: 500,
  child: Card(
    semanticContainer: true,
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
    child: Image.network(
      'https://placeimg.com/640/480/any', fit: BoxFit.fill,),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
    ),
    elevation: 5,
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  ),
),
```

Comment: If the Container is nested in another widget, the width & height may not get applied as expected. You can [overcome this by wrapping that Container in an Align widget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54717843/3291390).

Answer (score 17):

Time is moving, prefer you that:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html

```dart
SizedBox(
  height: double.infinity,
  child: Card(
    semanticContainer: true,
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
    child: Image.network(
      'https://placeimg.com/640/480/any', 
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
    ),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
    ),
    elevation: 5,
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  ),
),
```