# Child Container's Height is depending on parent Container's Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I Creating a Container giving it a height and width responsively, but the issue is that in the child of Container I use a ListView to show some Cards which are basically container and I give them a constant height but the height of the card are totally depending on Container's height, even if I give the of cards to 0, nothing will happen, and when I increase the container height, the card height increases, same happens while decreasing. this never happens to me before in flutter, may be this is a new version, I need help, please give answers with an explanation. You can see the Code of the container and Card.

***Container Code***

```
 Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 0),
          child: Container(
            child: ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              children: sample
                  .map((obj) => card.PredictionCard(
                      temprature: obj.temprature, status: obj.status))
                  .toList(),
            ),
            height: _device.height * 0.22,
            decoration: cardDecoration,
          ),
        ),
```

***Card Code***

```
class PredictionCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final temprature;
  final status;

  const PredictionCard({this.temprature, this.status});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: 10,
        ),
        height: 120,
        decoration: predictionCardDecoration,
        width: 100,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              '$temprature',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 40,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              '$status',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15, letterSpacing: 1),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 5),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Image(
                      image: AssetImage('assets/rainIcon.png'),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '23%',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15, letterSpacing: 1),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Image.asset('assets/rainDropIcon.png'),
                    Text(
                      '0%',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15, letterSpacing: 1),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

***Code of Class from where Responsive height is integrated***

```
// widget binging method
class DeviceConfig {
  final height = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.physicalSize.height /
      WidgetsBinding.instance.window.devicePixelRatio;
  final width = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.physicalSize.width /
      WidgetsBinding.instance.window.devicePixelRatio;
}


// using media query {uses context to set value of device configuration}
class DeviceConfigQuery {
  var height;
  var width;
  DeviceConfigInit(BuildContext context) {
    height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I will allow myself to copy the answer from another post as its worth to **remember** that and I woudnt put it better.

> Constraints in Flutter works a bit different than usual. Widgets
> themselves do not have constraints.
>
> When you specify a width/height on a Container, you're not
> constraining Container. You're constraining the child of Container.
>
> Container will then size itself based on the size of its child.
>
> As such, parent widgets always have the last word on how their
> descendants should be sized.
>
> If you want to go around this, you have to use Align widget:

```
 Container(   
     width: 200.0,
     height: 200.0, 
     child: Align(
       alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
       child: Container(
         width: 50.0,
         height: 50.0,
         decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.red),
       ),
     ),
 );
```

> This may seem weird and limiting. But this single weirdness is the
> reason why Flutter's layout is so powerful and composable.

answered by:
Rémi Rousselet in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/54717843/2945977

In your example instead of using `Padding`, use `Align` with `alignment: Alignment.center`